# Sublime Text 3 switched my tabs to be 2 spaces instead of 4

Tags: sublimetext3

For some reason my Sublime Text automatically switched my tabs to translate into 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces, and I'm not sure where or why it started doing that. Its only on one file and I only just realized, so it wasn't a recent development that I can undo. Any idea of why it would do that or how to fix it? I already set the tab size to be 4 in user settings so its not that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sublime Text Indentation Settings Being Overwritten By a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505213/sublime-text-indentation-settings-being-overwritten-by-a-file)

Comment: Keith's link certainly should sort it out but the quick answer is: click on the Sublime Text status bar (at the bottom) where it says `Spaces: Num` or `Tab Size: Num`. The context menu which opens allows users to set the indentation to use tabs or spaces, to control the indentation size/width, and to convert the current file from tabs to spaces and visa-versa.

Comment: I found the issue, indentations under view was set to tab size: 2 instead of tab size: 4

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the under the 'View' tab and 'Indentation', the tab size somehow got changed from Tab Width: 4 to Tab Width: 2. Fixed by setting it back to Tab Width: 4